# Only generate debugging output while running tests

Tags: testing, rust, conditional-statements, rust-cargo, conditional-compilation

Rust/Cargo have nice build and testing functionality that are built in, and you can differentiate how you want to build and run code with `cargo build`, `cargo build --release`, `cargo run`, and `cargo test`.

Suppose I have a function `foo()` that I want to call in a unit test. I want to include some debugging output, so that if if the test fails, I get some useful output. However, I don't want output to appear (or ideally have any runtime impact) if I do a debug build with `cargo build`/`cargo run` or a release build with `cargo build --release`. I only want this output to appear if I fail a test with `cargo test`.

The function `foo()` is opaque to the unit test, so I'm not just looking to output print statements in the unit test code, I want to instrument the function `foo()` itself. For example, in C you can do this with compiler `#ifdef`s and build the program multiple times for unit test vs. debug vs. release. I'm hoping for something easier, like an automatic `testprint!()` macro that works just like `print!()` does normally.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "For example, in C you can do this with compiler #ifdefs and build the program multiple times for unit test vs. debug vs. release. I'm hoping for something easier, like an automatic testprint!() macro that works just like print!() does normally." What exactly is this about? Syntax? Build process? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`cfg(test)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#test):

```
if cfg!(test) { print!(...); }
```

You can make your own macro for this using `macro_rules!`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros.html, https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html#declarative-macros-with-macro_rules-for-general-metaprogramming, https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html